# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in mail.php in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/demouser/public_html/abc/system/library/mail.php on line 170Notice:

This error show after calling payment getaway.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. Probably you are doing some math without the proper brackets / integer / float values.